# How to read a json file located in the root of a Xamarin solution?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I can currently successfully read data in my resources-folder looking like this:

```
var ResourceName = "Resources.MyData.json";
var JSON = new System.IO.StreamReader(typeof(Strings).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(ResourceName)).ReadToEnd();
```

But what if i want to read a file that is located in the root of the project and store the data from App.cs?

Comment: A bare relative path is relative to the project root.

Comment: Saving and Loading Files: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/#Loading_and_Saving_Files

Comment: @JSteward The solution I am currently working with has a "Model" folder in the root of the project. Inside this folder I have a .cs file that needs to work with a JSON-file that is located in the root of the project. Trying to break it down step by step, how would u recommend me to go about it? In my question I try to gather it from App.cs but maybe I should gather it from the .cs file inside the model that sets value based on the info in the JSON.

Comment: just use File.ReadAllText("file.json")

Comment: The path to the JSON file in the root of your project is simply the filename of the JSON file.

Comment: @JSteward I did try that where i used this code in App.cs. I got a crash on the `var JSON..` line with the following errormessage: `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: stream`

Comment: If the code you posted is what you're now referring to then it wouldn't work because in this code your accessing a resource which is usually located in a resource folder not the root.

Comment: File.ReadAllText returns a string containing the file data, not a stream

Comment: @JSteward That was an example when it works, if i have it in my resoruces folder. If i then remove "Resources." in the path and move the json to the root, then i get the errormessage i posted above

Comment: @Jason I have yet to try your solution.

Comment: You should use @Jason suggestion, that's the easiest way to access any text file in your projects root.

Comment: Ok. "File" is red when i implement that code. I cannot seem to find an assembly either.

Comment: With cursor on file type Ctl+. or `using System.IO` you'll either need to be in your platform specific project or .net standard project.

Comment: I did add that but still cannot reach it hmm

Comment: @JSteward Still failing to resolve this when trying to gather json from App.cs. By adding System.IO i still fail to add `File`, assumingly because my projectstructure doesnt support it. (Is there a way i can look? I am working with an old project which i didnt take part of creating in the first place). What other options do i have?

Comment: What type of project are you working with?

Comment: @JSteward I dont know where to find that exactly but it says `.Net Portable PCL 4.5` if look under Project -> General

Comment: PCL does not support the standard File api, use the link provided by SushiHangover to use the Xamarin service locator to access files.

Comment: @JSteward Gives me the null crash as mentioned above. Looks like i cant gather files from the root with that method. I tried to gather it like this "myjson.json" straight away and also when adding the first folder before "projectmainfolder.myjson.json" but with the same outcome.